# How to Crease the Edges Correctly?

Tags: modeling, workflow, edges, subdivision-surface, topology

In the picture below I use subdivision and I want to make the angle of this half circle hole sharp

[image]

But when I do edge crease, the topology overlaps and creates bad shading;
[image]

I don't want to add a support loop because of it's effect on the curvature of the whole cylinder.
I also tried bevel, but that creates  a triangle that ruins the topology also.

Does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 3):

Here's another possible flow for your support loops:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perfect solution!

Comment: Hi @AlexandreMarcati ! As you say, there are quite a few. This one costs you a slight bevel in the corners.. maybe acceptable.

Comment: Thanks ,  that a great idea

Answer (score 2):

The edge crease tool is very limited and will not give a good result in every situation. In my experience situations such as the one you're showing have to be dealt with good old retopology techniques.

Adding loops doesn't have to mess with the curve of the cylinder. Here is a suggestion on how you could deal with that crease without messing with the roundness of the cylinder and still having only quads (although I used two diamond-like faces, they're still quads - except for the big N-gon in the bottom of the hole that was already there, I mean):
[image]

This is just one possibility that you can try out and see if the result is good enough. But you can come up with other, perhaps better, solutions on your own if you do some trial and error.

Comment: thanks that helpful !